# How get google universal analytics dimensions using tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

i am trying to implement tracking with tag manager in our site....

is there any way to get google universal analytics dimensions through tag manager?

i need similar method like ga.getByName(); in analytics.js

Comment: what are you trying to do? normally you talk with GTM via dataLayer - is there something specific you'd like to do with tracker object from frontend?

Answer (score 0):

### Google Tag Manager

You can create a new Tag of type "Universal Analytics" and then specify your Custom Dimensions under `More settings` -> `Custom Dimensions`.

Index must be an integer value (1-20 for Basic version of Google Analytics)

Both Index & Value accept a Makro to dynamically fill in data.

### Google Analytics

In Google Analytics you need to specify what Custom Dimensions you expect to get in the Property settings of your account: `Custom Definitions` -> `Custom Dimensions`.

The "Index" that you set here has to match with what you specified as index for the dimension in the Tag inside Google Tag Manager.

See the official documentation about details on which scope to choose:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets

Comment: Need help regarding GTM in android.If I implement GTM in application then does it need to implement Analytics in Application too? If not then how GTm data will be reflected to Analytics

Comment: @Pankaj No. You implement GTM once in your application and then configure in the GTM web-interface what data to send to which Analytics provider. GTM will handle the integration of your Analytics provider(s) into the app for you (based on the "Tags", "Triggers" and "Variables" you configured in the GTM web-interface). I suggest you to read the introduction here: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/

Comment: ,I have already implemented GTM according to get started official site,and linked google analytics with GTM container.But no data is reflecting on analytics,ofcourse I am making some mistake somewhere but there is lack of How To Do instruction which is bothering me so much.

Comment: @Pankaj Have you published a new version or are you in preview mode? What do you see in the logs (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/#preview-publish ) ? Have you any active filtering rules on your GA property?